# Over how to separate UpdateTarget and Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, window-functions

Imagine following table with columns

```
TrackingID | CompletionIndicator | Flag2
```

Now I want to count all positions on Tracking ID level with `Completion Indicator = 0` but I want to update on Tracking ID level.

With below code only lines with 0 are updated. (logically!). But how can I separate the filter and the update target?

```
UPDATE UPDATETarget
SET Flag2 = New_Index
FROM (
    SELECT Flag2
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (
            PARTITION BY TrackingID ORDER BY id DESC
            ) AS New_Index
    FROM [dbo].Feedback
    WHERE CompletionIndicator = 0
    ) AS UPDATETarget
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2014, sorry I tagged it now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you can have multiple entries of TrackingID in this table. 
So probably this will do what you want to do, a bit old-style, with WITH it is more recommended

```
UPDATE FB
SET Flag2 = Src.NewIndex
FROM [dbo].Feedback AS FB
    JOIN    
        (SELECT TrackingID, COUNT(*) AS NewIndex
        FROM [dbo].Feedback 
        WHERE CompletionIndicator = 0
        GROUP BY TrackingID) AS Src
        ON Src.TrackingID = FB.TrackingID;
```

I would suggest always double-check what you expect to update by that query with SELECT first.

```
SELECT FB.*, Src.NewIndex
FROM [dbo].Feedback AS FB
    JOIN    
        (SELECT TrackingID, COUNT(*) AS NewIndex
        FROM [dbo].Feedback 
        WHERE CompletionIndicator = 0
        GROUP BY TrackingID) AS Src
        ON Src.TrackingID = FB.TrackingID;
```

Comment: You should probably change this to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: if David wants to update all the table then yes, you are right it should be LEFT JOIN, I am still not sure about the task

Comment: . . The OP implies that the query should update rows with `0` values.